# Native Base Picker generating "Unsafe legacy lifecycles"

Tags: react-native, native-base

I created a very simple page in react native. However, I'm getting the warning:

Warning: Unsafe legacy lifecycles will not be called for components using new component APIs.

%s uses %s but also contains the following legacy lifecycles:%s%s%s

The above lifecycles should be removed. Learn more about this warning here:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html, Styled(PickerNB), getDerivedStateFromProps(), , 
  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps,

It is happening because the native-base Picker. If I remove the picker, I do not receive the warning.

```
...
class ChangeProperty extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedProperty: '1'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProperties(); // It just loads a properties data from action component
  }

  onChangeProperty(value) {
    this.setState({
      selectedProperty: value
    });
  }

  updatePropertyBTN = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('CurrentPropertyID', this.state.selectedProperty);
    NavigationService.navigate('iRent');
  }

  ...
  <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            iosHeader="Select Property"
            placeholder="Property"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
            selectedValue={this.state.selectedProperty}
            textStyle={{ color: '#C0C0C0' }}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            onValueChange={(text) => this.onChangeProperty(text)}
          >
          {Object.keys(this.props.properties).map((key) => {
              return (
                <Picker.Item
                  label={this.props.properties[key]}
                  value={key}
                  key={key}
                />
              );
          })}
   </Picker>
}
```

It is not causing any error in my code, but the warning message in the terminal is disturbing me because I do not know what is causing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning is occurring because the NativeBase picker appears to be using legacy life cycle methods (*eg* componentWillReceiveProps like was mentioned in the warning) that are no longer supported by React - this has nothing to do with your code.

Ensure your NativeBase is updated to the latest package version and if it is you can raise an issue on their repo [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase)

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version. Thank you